# Persisting 2 table with the same generated id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, hibernate-entitymanager

I try to persist one parent entity which is joined with another child entity, but the problem is that the id is not generated for this child when persisting so I have this error :  `[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("L2S$OWNER"."SABRI"."TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID")`

there is the child Entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(MyLibrarySabriEntityPK.class)
@Table(name = "SABRI", schema = "L2S$OWNER", catalog = "")

public class MyLibrarySabriEntity extends ActionForm {
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX")
private MyLibraryTestEntity sabriEntity;

@Id
private String RATING_ID_ROW;

@Id
private String RATING_ID_COL;


@Basic
@Column(name = "TRANSITION_PROBABILITY", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 20)
private Double TRANSITION_PROBABILITY;}
```

the PK class :

```
@Data
public class MyLibrarySabriEntityPK implements Serializable {
private String TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID;
private String RATING_ID_ROW;
private String RATING_ID_COL;


public MyLibrarySabriEntityPK(String TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID,String RATING_ID_COL,String RATING_ID_ROW ){
    this.TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID=TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID;
    this.RATING_ID_COL = RATING_ID_COL;
    this.RATING_ID_ROW= RATING_ID_ROW;
}
```

}

there is the parent Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "L2S$OWNER", catalog = "")
public class MyLibraryTestEntity extends ActionForm {

    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sabriEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private final List<MyLibrarySabriEntity> entities = new ArrayList<MyLibrarySabriEntity>(25);

    public void addEntitysabri(MyLibrarySabriEntity entity) {
        getEntities().add(entity);
        entity.setSabriEntity(this);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "IdGenerated")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "IdGenerated", strategy = "dao.Identifier")
    @Column(name = "ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 10)
    private String ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX;


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "REFERENCE", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
    private Integer reference;}
```

And here I try to persist the parent table which is supposed to persist also the child table but the Id is not generated !

```
MyLibrarySabriEntity Entity = null;
MyLibraryTestEntity test = getMyLibraryTestEntity(matrixStartDate, matrixName);  // here I get the values of my entity test (parent)
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
                double val = cells.get(row + FIRST_ROW, col + FIRST_COL).getDoubleValue();
                Entity = getMyLibrarySabriEntity(col, row, val); // this get the values of the Entity parameters (child)
                Entity.setSabriEntity(test);
                test.addEntitysabri(Entity);
                em.persist(test);
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction.isActive())
            transaction.rollback();
        LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage(), e);

    } finally {
        if (transaction.isActive())
            transaction.commit();
        em.close();

    }
```

Comment: looks like, not properly configure dependent beans, please check again.

Comment: why does the title says "same generated id"? Child entity 'MyLibraryTestEntity' wlll have its own id and parent entity will have its own, provided you configure beans' dependency properly.

Comment: MyLibraryTestEntity it's the parent entity and the child entity is MyLibrarySabriEntity , you're right it's not the same id because the child id has 3 id so , I mean the value of generated id of parent entity will be the same of the value of the column TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID of my child entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using JPA 2.0+

Remove this mapping completely:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID", nullable = false, 
       insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 100)
private String TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID;
```

and put the `@Id` directly on the ManyToOne and **remove the insertable and updateable attributes.**

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX")
private MyLibraryTestEntity sabriEntity;
```

Update your ID class accordingly. Any previous reference to `TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID` should be replaced with a reference to `sabriEntity`. You are also confusing @EmbeddedId and @IdClass: Only the former would contain column definitions whereas you are using the latter approach.

```
public class MyLibrarySabriEntityPK implements Serializable {

    private String sabriEntity;
    private String RATING_ID_ROW;
    private String RATING_ID_COL;
}
```

See:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#JPA_2.0

Comment: I did that but I have this error : "Unable to find properties (TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID) in entity annotated with @IdClass:model.MyLibrarySabriEntity " and the problem is that I can't remove it because I have 3 column as Id not just 2 !

Comment: The property in the ID class should match the property in the Entity so that will be `sabriEntity` and not `TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID`

Comment: I tried to remove it but I had the same error " cannot insert NULL into ("L2S$OWNER"."SABRI"."TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID") " .

Comment: I would also suggest that having insertable and updateable set to false on the JoinColumn is unlikely to be doing much good.

Comment: When I set him to true , it gives me this error " Repeated column in mapping for entity: model.MyLibrarySabriEntity column: TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID " which is normal because I had already the column with the same name

Comment: Remove all annotations from your IDClass: you are confusing EmbeddedID and IDClass. The process using the latter  is clearly detailed in the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I did what you just say on your comment and I remove the insertable and updateable attributes but it gives me the error " Unable to find properties (TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID) in entity annotated with @IdClass:model.MyLibrarySabriEntity " even if I add "@Id" to JoinColumn.

Comment: I have provided a link to documentation clearly outlining the process and attempted to provide an answer in line with this using the info you have given. You should be able to logically work through the process form this. If you want any further help then you should update your question to show all 3 classes as they look after the proposed changes because if you still have an error around a missing property 'TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID' you have clearly not followed the answer.

Comment: I update the 3 classes and know I have this error :" Property of @IdClass not found in entity model.MyLibrarySabriEntity: TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID  " Just for your information, the 3 classes with persistence mapping are generated by my database schema .

Comment: Okay, so change the property TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID to sabriEntity in the generated IDClass as advised and see what happens.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you  using?

Comment: Then I tried to add my  "TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID"  attribut but i had error saying that  I must add insertable = false and updatable=false in joincolumn , I add it but know I have the first error which is "cannot insert NULL into ("L2S$OWNER"."SABRI"."TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID")" I checked the Id of my parent entity by debugging and I found that he is not null, but the id of child entity = null.

Comment: CHANGE THE PROPERTY IN THE ID CLASS AS I HAVE SHOWN. THAT IS ALL YOU NEED TO DO.

Comment: THANY YOUUUUU VERY MUCH ALAN ! IT WORKS !!

Comment: Ok, You should mark the answer as correct. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to Alan Hay, I found the problem , I change the property TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID of my IDclass to sabriEntity and I delete all the annotation of this class !

Child entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@IdClass(MyLibrarySabriEntityPK.class)
@Table(name = "SABRI", schema = "L2S$OWNER", catalog = "")
public class MyLibrarySabriEntity extends ActionForm {

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@ManyToOne
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSITION_MATRIX_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX")
private MyLibraryTestEntity sabriEntity;


@Id
private String RATING_ID_ROW;

@Id
private String RATING_ID_COL;


@Basic
@Column(name = "TRANSITION_PROBABILITY", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 20)
private Double TRANSITION_PROBABILITY;
```

Parent Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "L2S$OWNER", catalog = "")
public class MyLibraryTestEntity extends ActionForm {

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sabriEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private final List<MyLibrarySabriEntity> entities = new ArrayList<MyLibrarySabriEntity>(25);

public void addEntitysabri(MyLibrarySabriEntity entity) {
    getEntities().add(entity);
    entity.setSabriEntity(this);
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "IdGenerated")
@GenericGenerator(name = "IdGenerated", strategy = "dao.Identifier")
@Column(name = "ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, length = 10)
private String ID_TRANSITION_MATRIX;


@Basic
@Column(name = "REFERENCE", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
private Integer reference;
```

PK Class

```
@Data
public class MyLibrarySabriEntityPK implements Serializable {
private MyLibraryTestEntity sabriEntity;
private String RATING_ID_ROW;
private String RATING_ID_COL;

public MyLibrarySabriEntityPK() {
}

public MyLibrarySabriEntityPK(MyLibraryTestEntity sabriEntity,String RATING_ID_COL,String RATING_ID_ROW ){
this.sabriEntity=sabriEntity;
this.RATING_ID_COL = RATING_ID_COL;
this.RATING_ID_ROW= RATING_ID_ROW;
```

}

}